# Read first characters of a variable in bash script?

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I have a file where i get some informations through a bash script to put data in a DB table and i'd like to know how to read the first characters of a variable because if it starts with "CE-" that line's data will go into a table if not they must be inserted in an other one, how can i do this?

Comment: Have you tried searching for a solution, this is a common question.

Answer (score 0):

Like this-

```
var=CE-xxxxx
echo "$var"
output- CE-xxxxx

var2=$(echo "$var" | cut -c 1-3)
echo "$var2"
output- CE-
```

Then you can check if `$var2` matches your criteria and use it further.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `cut` to get the bytes that you need:

```
V="CE-IMPORTANT"
I=$(echo $V | cut -b 4-)
```

If you want to use the - as separator:

```
I=$(echo $V | cut -d '-' -f 2)
```

In both cases you get "IMPORTANT" in I var